# flutter:how to use function with parameter in constructor with state

Tags: flutter, dart

i created a widget and i want to use it many times ,i need its buttons onpressed method use the state value and each buttons make different function which i give by constructor, but button didnt work and when state changes function runs(i dont want), i want func runs only buttons pressed.if takes no parameter buttons works , but i need func with parameters

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Myapp());
}

class Myapp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyappState createState() => _MyappState();
}

class _MyappState extends State<Myapp> {
  final item1 = MyClass(
    myfunc: (double myvalue) {
      switch (myvalue.toString()) {
        case "0.0":
          {
            print(" first");
          }
          break;
        case "1.0":
          {
            print(" second");
          }
          break;

        case "2.0":
          {
            print(" third");
          }
          break;
        default:
      }
    },
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("my app"),
          ),
          body: Center(child: item1)),
    );
  }
}

class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final int num1;
  final Function(double) myfunc;

  const MyClass({Key key, this.myfunc, this.num1}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> {
  double myvalue = 0.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Slider(
                value: myvalue,
                divisions: 2,
                min: 0,
                max: 2,
                onChanged: (double newvalue) {
                  setState(() {
                    myvalue = newvalue;
                    print("my value: $myvalue");
                  });
                }),
            RaisedButton(child: Text("button"), onPressed: widget.myfunc(myvalue))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually did it but there is a small mistake, here is the solution; `RaisedButton(child: Text("button"), onPressed: () => widget.myfunc(myvalue))`, you can't give a function with value directly to the button, you need declare a function and put your function inside it.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Myapp());
}

class Myapp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyappState createState() => _MyappState();
}

class _MyappState extends State<Myapp> {
  final item1 = MyClass(
    myfunc: (double myvalue) {
      print("value $myvalue");
      switch (myvalue.toString()) {
        case "0":
          {
            print(" first");
          }
          break;
        case "1.0":
          {
            print(" second");
          }
          break;

        case "2.0":
          {
            print(" third");
          }
          break;
        default:
      }
    },
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("my app"),
          ),
          body: Center(child: item1)),
    );
  }
}

class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  final int num1;
  final Function(double) myfunc;

  const MyClass({Key key, this.myfunc, this.num1}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> {
  double myvalue = 0.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Slider(
                value: myvalue,
                divisions: 2,
                min: 0,
                max: 2,
                onChanged: (double newvalue) {
                  setState(() {
                    myvalue = newvalue;
                    print("my value: $myvalue");
                  });
                }),
            RaisedButton(child: Text("button"), onPressed: () => widget.myfunc(myvalue))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```